# How to disable suggest directories zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

zsh automatically suggests directories in the current working directory.

How to disable it?

[image]

Comment: When is it suggesting? What do you press for it to suggest?

Comment: It auto show there, I didn't press anything. I have installed zsh-autosuggestions